# Proving $\frac{\log_a x}{\log_c x} = \frac{\log_a x - \log_b x}{\log_b x - \log_c x}$, when $b^2=ac$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I came across a question in my textbook that I couldn't solve nor find the solution of:

> If $b^2 = ac$, and $a, b, c$ are positive integers that are unnequal to each other and not equal to 1, prove that
> $$\frac{\log_a x}{\log_c x} = \frac{\log_a x - \log_b x}{\log_b x - \log_c x}$$

From the first statement, it is known that $2 \log b = \log a + \log c$, but evaluating it always results in an expression without any logarithm of x:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\log_a x}{log_c x} & = \frac{\frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}}{\frac{\log_b x}{\log_b c}} \\
                         & = \frac{\log_b c}{\log_b a}
\end{align*}$$
I didn't know how to continue from this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: try and work backwards: write $\log_a x = \frac{\log x}{\log a}$ in your problem statement and try to eliminate $\log x$ from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle\frac{{{{\log }_a}x - {{\log }_b}x}}{{{{\log }_b}x - {{\log }_c}x}} = \frac{{{{\log }_a}x - {{\log }_a}x{{\log }_b}a}}{{{{\log }_c}x{{\log }_b}c - {{\log }_c}x}} = \frac{{{{\log }_a}x}}{{{{\log }_c}x}}.\frac{{1 - {{\log }_b}a}}{{{{\log }_b}c - 1}}\\
{b^2} = ac \Rightarrow {\log _b}{b^2} = {\log _b}a + {\log _b}c \Leftrightarrow {\log _b}a + {\log _b}c = 2\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow {\log _b}a = 2 - {\log _b}c \Rightarrow \frac{{{{\log }_a}x - {{\log }_b}x}}{{{{\log }_b}x - {{\log }_c}x}} = \frac{{{{\log }_a}x}}{{{{\log }_c}x}}.\frac{{1 - 2 + {{\log }_b}c}}{{{{\log }_b}c - 1}} = \frac{{{{\log }_a}x}}{{{{\log }_c}x}}.\frac{{{{\log }_b}c - 1}}{{{{\log }_b}c - 1}}\\
 \displaystyle= \frac{{{{\log }_a}x}}{{{{\log }_c}x}}
\end{array}$$